# Unable to select files form UIDocumentPickerViewController Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5

I am working on UIDocumentPickerViewController() in swift. After opening the document picker the files and images look blur and I can't able to select anyone of them. I have attached the screenshot and the code below. Any idea why these files and images are not selectable.

[image: Files and images look are not selectable]

```
extension BecomeMuftiTwoVC: UIDocumentPickerDelegate {
    func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
        guard let selectedFilesURL = urls.first else {
            return
        }
        let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let sandboxFileURL = dir.appendingPathComponent(selectedFilesURL.lastPathComponent)
        
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: sandboxFileURL.path) {
            print("Already File Exist")
        }
        else {
            
            do{
                try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: selectedFilesURL, to: sandboxFileURL)
                print("Copied Files")
            }
            catch{
                print("Files Are not exist ")
                
            }
        }
    }
}
//MARK: - Import File Btn Action
@IBAction func importFile(_ sender: Any) {
    let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [KUTTypedPlainText], in: .import)
    documentPicker.delegate = self
    documentPicker.allowsMultipleSelection = false
    present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your line

```
let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [KUTTypedPlainText], in: .import)
```

seems to initialize a document picker for plain-text files only.

Try this instead:

```
let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [kUTTypeImage as String], in: .import)
```

Also, be careful as the initializer `init(documentTypes:in:)` is deprecated since iOS14.0. So for iOS14 and above, you should use:

```
let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes: [.heic, .heif, .livePhoto, .image])
```